# Hyperlink activated directly from button rather than underlined text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For styling purposes, would like to activate Outlook Express, or whatever, directly from clicking a button, rather than clicking a button which causes "Click here to send Email" to be displayed and then clicking "Click here to send Email".

Suggestions as to how to achieve objective will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Ivan Rutter

Comment: Be more descriptive and maybe you want supply some code ;) otherwise you probably will be voted down to hell ;)

Comment: Does it have to be <button> or something, that looks like a button?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this ?

**html**

```
<button class="email" data-email="some@email.com">whatever</button>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.email').click(function(){
   window.location = 'mailto:' + $(this).data('email');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean

```
<input type="button" value="Send Mail" onclick="location='mailto:whoever@wherever.com';" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="mailto:my.name@example.com">Mail me!</a>
```

Clicking this link will automatically open the system's default e-mail client. See here for more details on `mailto`: http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html.

Edit: if you want it to look like a button, stick a button-like image in your `<a>`.

Comment: Not sure why the dv: to my mind this is a much cleaner solution and works with no js.

Comment: I guess it's because of the use of the word *button* in the question, and *javascript* in the tags. However I'm not sure the OP knows that you can style links to *look* like a button, so have a +1 from me. I think you should suggest using CSS tweaks rather than an image though.